# Pushing the last 2 li elements to the right

Tags: css

What if I want to keep the positioning of the first li, but the second and third li I would like pushed to the furthest right, so I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

**So far I have the following:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakeguybrushthreepwood/LqLFt/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class=" ">
<ul class="container">
    <li>Link One</li>
    <li>Link Two</li>
    <li>Link Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.container li {
    width: 30px;
    display:inline;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll probably have more than three elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? So we can select 2 and 3 like this, and float them to the right. Pretty simple. These do swap the last 2 links.

### CSS:

```
.container li:nth-child(n+2) {
    width: 80px;
    display:inline;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LqLFt/1/)

---

Well pointed out in the comments by **Gaby aka G. Petrioli**:

```
:nth-last-child(-n+2)
```

Can also be used.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LqLFt/10/)

---

Simply put the last 2 links the opposite way round to solve the swap. The swap is caused by `float: right;`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LqLFt/11/)

Comment: What if he has more than 3 elements ?

Comment: You should better use `:nth-last-child(-n+2)` but still it changes the order of the two last elements..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Well pointed out. Also can whoever downvoted explain?

Comment: Hey - but why is three the furthest one and two the second furthest one. I just wanted it Link One, Link Two, Link Three.

Comment: @fakeguybrushthreepwood Read the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: Hmm I didn't realise that I had to swap around the elements, this actually really causes problems with the responsive design layout I am using.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container li+li{
    float: right;  
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

With the + selector you get all li which directly follow after another li.

This will result in all elements after the first list point being on the right hand side.

http://jsfiddle.net/LqLFt/4/

Comment: It swaps the last 2 links around, which isn't the desired effect. It isn't a good idea for me to change the HTML either due to responsive layout for mobile.

Comment: In that case I guess your only bet will be absolute positioning of the second and third link.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.container li:first-child {
margin-right:95px;
}
```

Comment: @fakeguybrushthreepwood do not want change the order of the li's, so this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following changes :

```
.container li:nth-child(2),
.container li:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/LqLFt/6/

Comment: It swaps the last 2 links around, which isn't the desired effect. It isn't a good idea for me to change the HTML either due to responsive layout for mobile.